# How will WCF Service hosted in IIS7.5 react to the requests for which client terminates connection

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have two WCF services, ServiceA and ServiceB.  Both are hosted in IIS7.5 in different machines.

ServiceA is calling ServiceB, while ServiceB is processing the requests ServiceA terminates connection (due to IIS reset or some other reason) .

Now question is how will ServiceB react to those requests and how will that impact ServiceB worker process?

Comment: At a guess, ServiceB would continue to process any of the requests it had received.  I don't know (off the top of my head) if ServiceA begin offline would cause any errors when ServiceB sent the result back, however.  Ideally they should be isolated enough that ServiceB woudln't know or care if A was offline for the response.

Comment: By isolate, I mean that they're separate and there is no dependencies between them, other than the messages.  If ServiceA goes offline while waiting for ServiceB to finish processing the request, ServiceB shouldn't care.  If ServiceB can't finish because ServiceA is suddenly unavailable, then (IMO) the two services are too tightly coupled and you may want to rethink your design/approach.

Comment: Thanks Tim. can you explain what do you mean by isolated enough?
ServcieA and ServiceB are in different machines.
When ServiceA goes office what will happen in ServiceB while sending result back to ServiceA
1. As ServiceA is not there it will throw error , how will this impact worker process
2. Request processing thread will hung up
3. It will be handled gracefully at HTTP.sys level no impact on worker process 
In that scenario how will IIS behave, what are the possibilities of thread processing request in worker process being hung up for such requests?